# Trouble automating Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell

I'm trying put my credential in a website, for automate some tasks I have. I'm trying this code. And nothing happens.

```
$Url = "https://srvdcvs05.fiep_pr.br:1311/"
$Ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$Ie.Navigate( $Url )
$secLink = $Ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Continue to this website (not recommended).'}
$secLink.click()
$Ie.Document.getElementsByType("input") | where { $.Name -eq "user" }.value = "myuser"
$Ie.Document.getElementsByName("input") | where { $.Name -eq "password" }.value = "mypassword"
$loginBtn = $Ie.Document.getElementsById('input') | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'button' -and $_.Value -eq 'LoginButton'}
$loginBtn.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without knowing anything about the page.

That being said: two obvious mistakes that may be the reason for it:

```
# Your code: $Ie.Document.getElementsByType("input") | where { $.Name -eq "user" }.value = "myuser"
($Ie.Document.getElementsByType("input") | where { $_.Name -eq "user" }).value = "myuser"
# Your code: $Ie.Document.getElementsByName("input") | where { $.Name -eq "password" }.value = "mypassword"
($Ie.Document.getElementsByName("input") | where { $_.Name -eq "password" }).value = "mypassword"
```

So: accessing property for script block does not make sense (`{ }.value`) and `where` needs `$_.Property` rather than `$.Property`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for replay.

About it "$_.Property rather than $.Property." Was typed wrong, sorry about it.

But.. My initial problem is this function:

$secLink = $Ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Continue to this website (not recommended).'}

$secLink.click()

DON'T work. The website open, but the click on this message not.